# Form accept digit only?

Tags: html, forms

I have a form like this. I tried to change text type="text to digit" but it didn't work.
I want to accept only numbers.

```
<tr>
    <td width="100">
        <font face="arial" size="2">* Age</font>
    </td>
    <td width="250">
        <input id="your_age" name="your_age" type="digit" />
    </td>
```

Comment: Try to avoid using `face` attribute etc. Get into the habit of using style/css.

Comment: Did you google "html input number only" and find that [the top three results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=html+input+number+only) are on SO?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that using HTML tags if you not using HTML5. You need to do some sort of validation using javascript or php for accepting only numbers/digit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<input type="number">`. You may want to check if it's a number afterwards with PHP too though.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about a client-side verification, which has nothing to do with PHP.

In HTML5 you can use `type="number"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use as following if your working with HTML 5

```
 <input type="number" />
```